# How to create Dynamic table in ms sql?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a Membership form in asp.net  Which contains custom fields.so by that custom Field User can generate more than one field dynamically

**for Example** (User can add Mobile number column in their membership form (they can add what ever they need)).So i cant able to maintain static table for Membership control  in ms sql.
Is there any way to create dynamic table in ms sql for Dynamic Membership form.(whenever user adding column dynamcally i should get those column in ms sql dynamic table) 
 please help me to solve my problem

Comment: if i get you question properly..i think you should use `alter table ADD colum myuserNewlyaddedCol char(100)` ?  from this http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php

Comment: So when wenver the user `add's` that time you use `alter table ADD` to add columns to your table

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not a table of custom fields with 4 columns - an id, a link to your users table, the custom field name, and the custom field value?

Comment: but my application possible to have n number of custom fields so i cant able to enter all custom field values in sigle column 
for ex:User can add (first name last name phoneno birthday) so i just need to store each values in different column?